# Listview file for specific folder/directory

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello guy's can any body help me about a assignment given to us by our proof. I'm new to programming but I'm learning via Google, but upon searching in Google i can't seem to find my question so I'm using the platform as the last resort. But first things first pls Bare with me for my bad English...

My question is how can i load a Listview file with specific folder
Like for example it's on document but the thing is FolderBrowseDialog need to choose where folder should i load. Ty for the help

Comment: Try to tackle it one part after the other: how to select a folder, how to enumerate the files in a folder, and finally how to display the found file names in the list box.

Comment: Please provide an example of your best try on solving it, read how to [ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

## Lets do it step by step

---

- ### Getting the directory using [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog)

  - Add `System.IO` namespace on top of your form's code. like:

    `using System.IO;`
  - Add all needed controls to your form. lets say Button, FolderBrowserDialog and ListView
  - Double click on the form to open code window for Button's click event.
  - Add the following code:

    ```
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath); 
    }
    ```

---

- ### Using the directory in ListView

  Use any of the code below that suites your requirements:
- #### To Only Show files:

Used [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) class to access the files in the directory and access their names.

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
   FileInfo[] Files = dir.GetFiles();
   foreach (FileInfo item in Files)
   {
       listView1.Items.Add(item.Name);
   }
}
```

---

- #### To Only Show directories:

Used [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo) class to read Subdirectories inside a folder and access their names.

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
   DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dir.GetDirectories();
   foreach (DirectoryInfo item in subdirs)
   {
       listView1.Items.Add(item.Name);
   }
}
```

---

- #### To Show everything:

Used [`FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo) class to query each file and directory and access their names.

```
if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
   FileSystemInfo[] allElements = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();
   foreach (FileSystemInfo item in allElements)
   {
       listView1.Items.Add(item.Name);
   }
}
```

---

## Overall code

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ListViewDirectory
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo item in files)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(item.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Output

---

[image]